# How to programmatically scroll a recyclerview over keyboard?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I have a `recyclerview` in which there is an edit text where it will hidden and opens up on click of some button.
Please refer to `screen 1`.

On click of reject or accept the view is displayed:

[image: on click of reject or accept the view is displayed]

Now, my `recyclerview` is expanding downwards but I want it to expand upward like this:

By default, it expands downward:

[image: by default, it expands downward]

I want it to expand upward like this:

[image: I want it to expand upward like this]

Similarly, when keyboard opens up I want the whole `recyclerview` cell just above the keyboard like this.

By default, it does not move upward:

[image: by default, it does not move upward]

I want something like this:

[image: I want something like this]

What should be the approach for this functionality?
Do I have to do the calculations of cell height, keyboard height or is there some other method for this.

Please attach related links.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this for my chat class you can rewrite this code snippet according to yours.

```
private boolean keyboardShown(View rootView) {

    final int softKeyboardHeight = 100;
    Rect r = new Rect();
    rootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);
    DisplayMetrics dm = rootView.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int heightDiff = rootView.getBottom() - r.bottom;
    return heightDiff > softKeyboardHeight * dm.density;
}

messageEditText.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            if (keyboardShown(messageEditText.getRootView())) {
                Log.d("keyboard", "keyboard UP");

                if (keyboardUp == false) {
                    if (results.size() > 0)
                        chatList.smoothScrollToPosition(results.size()+1);
                    keyboardUp = true;
                }

            } else {
                Log.d("keyboard", "keyboard Down");
                keyboardUp = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: didn't work out. can you please explain me the approach?

Answer (score 0):

Let's divide the question into two, scroll down the RecyclerView and show the cell when the keyboard is shown.

1. just use the `scrollToPosition(index)` with to the cell index
2. you can just change the android:windowSoftInputMode to be adjustSize in the activity:

   ```
   <activity
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
   android:name=".MainActivity"
   android:label="@string/app_name">
   <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
   ```

or just in the fragment:

```
        window.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
```

Comment: android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
not working